# wrap each text block of certain length into its own div using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, for-loop, each, word-wrap

I'd like to wrap a block of text into divs such that each div has the same number of characters. The goal is to make divs that can be clicked between like pages of a book, i.e.,  pagination. I'm having trouble though with the each() statement to wrap each segment of the text block into its own div of equal length.

Jere's the code Hhich works for one div but doesn't yet work to make multiple divs:

HTML:

```
<div id="content">hi my name is joe. I work at a school.</div>
<div id="count"></div>
<button>wrap</button>
```

javaScript:

```
$('button').on('click', function(){ 
  var content=$('#content').text();
  $('#count').text(content.length);        
  /*   var length20; //20 character long text block
    if(content.length>=20);
      $.each(length20, function(){
    length20.wrap('<div class="new" />');   
    }            
 */ 
});
```

here's [the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/trpeters1/BRtDY/15/) if you'd like to edit the code directly.

If someone might be able to edit this fiddle to fix its `each()` statement I'd be very appreciative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
$('button').on('click', function(){ 
     var content=$('#content').text();
     //'5'-length blocks
     var parts = content.match(/.{1,5}/g);
     $('#count').text(parts.length);   
     $.each( parts, function( index, part ){
        $("body").append ('<div class="New">'+part+'</div>')
     });
});​
```

Comment: hi thanks so much, that works great! Since this cuts off sentences I realized I should probably match based on having a "." too. Can you help with the regex to match based on length AND ending with a period? The period takes priority but still needs to close to the length specified.

Comment: @timpeterson Split your content by period sign/s and apply `match`ing for each  part. Then combine all parts with period signs. Btw I have update my `regexp`. Use that one.

Comment: thanks, Hmm, here's the new fiddle with your edits. http://jsfiddle.net/BRtDY/19/. It still seems to prioritize length over the period punctuation. Is there any way to reverse that prioritization?

Comment: You did not understand my comment correctly, when I was talking about `splitting` .Anyway look at this http://jsfiddle.net/BRtDY/20/